# How to go through two colours with sine wave in p5.js

Tags: javascript, colors, trigonometry, p5.js

I know how to do it with black and white

```js
let a = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(map(sin(a), -1, 1, 0, 255));
  rect(20, 20, 50);
  a += 0.01;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLwZS.gif)

I would like it to be purple instead of black but I can't do it.
I would like to achieve something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWduu.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know much about p5.js. But simple googling and would offer this solution

```js
let a = 0;
let white;
let purple;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  white = color(255, 255, 255);
  purple = color(160, 32, 240);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  const temp = map(sin(a), -1, 1, 0, 1);
  fill(lerpColor(white, purple, temp));
  rect(20, 20, 50);
  a += 0.01;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

With lerp color you could create implementation that supports even more colors.

```
let white = color(255, 255, 255); // at 0 (-1 on sin)
let purple = color(160, 32, 240); // at 0.5 ( 0 on sin)
let blue = color(0,0,255);  // at 1 (1 on sin)

let temp = map(sin(a),-1,1,0,1);
if(temp < 0.5){
   let temp2 = map(temp, 0, 0.5, 0, 1);
   result = lerpColor(white, purple, temp2);
} else {
   let temp2 = map(temp, 0.5, 1, 0, 1);
   result = lerpColor(purple, blue, temp2);
}
```

With some refactoring and more work this could support arbitrary number of colors. You could have a sin go through the entire rainbow.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is [`colorMode(HSB)`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/colorMode). [Hue Saturation Brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) makes it easy to pick a purple hue (280 out of 360), then shift saturation and brightness to fade between grayscale and hue. Saturation and brightness range from 0 to 100.

In this case, I'm fading between 0 and 40 on saturation, and 60 and 100 on brightness. At one extreme, HSB of (280, 0, 100) is pure white. At the other extreme, (280, 40, 60) is purple.

```js
let a = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  colorMode(HSB);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  const v = map(sin(a), -1, 1, 0, 40);
  fill(280, v, 100 - v);
  rect(20, 20, 50);
  a += 0.01;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

[`lerpColor`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/lerpColor), mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72749691/6243352), is probably best for this case, but I'll leave my answer up since it offers some tweakability that `lerpColor` might not.